# Unexpected Termination in SSIS multithreading solution

Tags: c#, multithreading, ssis

Was following https://key2consulting.com/multithreading-an-ssis-package/ I could not see anywhere to post a comment on that specific site anyhow I get Unexpected Termination when I run via a job, all fine if I run locally in VS and all good when the called package is run by itself in its own job. So it must be the multithreading code that is bombing out, so I started adding FireInformation events and every time I run it, it seems to show inconsistent trail of information logs, so I am out of ideas. Any suggestions would be helpful. My code is not exactly the same to the letter as the above post as I have adlibbed for my purposes, and as I said it works when I run locally.
In the first line of the ICSPackage.ExecutePackage method I have a call:

`bool fireAgain = true; Dts.Events.FireInformation(1, "ICSPackage", "Thread" + threadInstanceNumber.ToString() + " execution", "", 0, ref fireAgain);`

that never gets fired.

Comment: That doesn't look like fun at all. A challenge with the current question is there's no way for people to diagnose what you've done or to propose fixes. MVP and all that. Line 36 of the scriptmain.cs is an if statement that determines whether we run the packages against the IS catalog or locally. I wonder if the challenge you're encountering is related to that?

Comment: ICSPackage.cs, no line number given, seems suspect. It "Sets the execution of the threads as asynchronous"  but then loops through testing the operation status and sleeps. Seems silly to me, just set SYNCHRONIZED to 1 and when it's done, it's done. Also, the call to MessageBox.Show is going to break when this is run on a server as you cannot interact with the UI. I'd replace any calls to that with Dts.Events.FireInformation/FireError based on criticality

Comment: Yeah I have since removed the message box as in only applicable when running it locally, changed it to log error event instead, but again no error log seen when I view the log in the SSMS log service.

Comment: I have checked all the libraries are present on the server surely it will thru a different error.

Comment: Maybe I am not being fair to whoever you are reading this I am thinking it is possibly a SQL Agent permission issue as my process does one thing but does 3 things in the process to do the one thing as in creates a CSV file as the end result, calls a database to get the list of tasks, tasks are all the same that is downloads a SSRS report as a byte stream then saves it to a network drive. Perhaps one or 3 of these processes the SQL Agent is lacking permissions. But then again it does not reach the first line of the Execute Package so ...

Comment: I think my next approach is to be sure as in remove all code from the Execute Package function and see what comes of it, the job should finish quickly if nothing is processed as all threads will complete.

Comment: Excellent that worked - so somewhere to start now some missing or permission perhaps.

Comment: Hmm - one line of code write to information log fails - gr8 like not. Maybe you cannot write to log in a thread. At lease now I can comment out one line of code until I find the possible cause.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @billinkc if only that you inspired me to accept the challenge. I finally got over the line and maybe it will help someone else to go over the line as well in the future.
2 lessons learnt:

1. Logging in a thread did not work
2. Mandatory required parameters really means mandatory

Logging in a thread as in `Dts.Events.FireInformation(1, "Thread" + threadInstance.ToString(), "Complete", "", 0, ref fireAgain);` did not work however; never say never! I made it work by adding an event handler to the ICSPackage so the caller (Main Script) can then invoke the event and thus I call the log event code in there. Worked like a charm .. so so happy. I was able to get the error message from the log ... yeeha ... so when I ran my job low and behold it led me to think ...

> The Execution from the SSIS Catalog Failed on Thread 1 with error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): In order to execute this package, you need to specify values for the required parameters.

@#$%^ Have a nice day everyone!!